# How do I use if statements with checkboxes without clutter

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, checkbox

I have this 
application with 13 checkboxes.
And i want to do if statements to check if a textbox is checked but its going to get really cluttered after checking 4 of them for example

```
if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }

else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true && checkBox2.isChecked = false)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }

else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == false && checkBox2.isChecked = true)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }

else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == false && checkBox3.isChecked = true)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }

else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == false && checkBox3.isChecked = false)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }


else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true && checkBox3.isChecked = false)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }

else if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true && checkBox3.isChecked = true)
    {
          DoSomething();          
    }
```

I bet you can see the pattern already.. I need to check *every possible solution* for 13 checkboxes, is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: is it `doSomething` always or `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and I am not able to catch your pattern. can u write 2-3 more conditions.

Comment: When after every condition we have to do `DoSomething()` than why do we need the condition at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

13 checkboxes give 2<sup>13</sup> = 8192 different combinations. Although it is hard to imagine a system that requires end-users to distinguish among so many distinct possibilities, making a program that responds to them is really straightforward.

Assign distinct "tags" from the interval 0..12, inclusive, to each check box. Walk through check boxes, and construct a bit mask from tags of checked boxes, as follows:

```
var mask = 0;
// Below, comparison == true is required
// because IsChecked is Nullable<bool>
if (checkBox0.IsChecked == true) mask |= 1 << 0;
if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true) mask |= 1 << 1;
if (checkBox2.IsChecked == true) mask |= 1 << 2;
if (checkBox3.IsChecked == true) mask |= 1 << 3;
...
if (checkBox12.IsChecked == true) mask |= 1 << 12;
```

Now `mask` has a value from 0 to 8191, inclusive, encoding each distinct combination of check marks. Create an array of 8192 actions corresponding to each combination, and call

```
action[mask]();
```

to invoke the action that corresponds to the selected combination.

Comment: Wow :) I was thinking in the right direction but i am sure I could not have reached till this solution. Awesome +1

Comment: That looks really complicated, Like I kinda understand it but I've never seen anything structured that way.

Comment: `someBitfield |= 1 << n;` is a pretty standard syntax. There's a corresponding form to set the `n`th bit to zero: `someBitfield &= ~(1 << n);`

Comment: @JonnyKhanas Using binary numbers to represent yes/no combinations is reasonably typical. Structuring combinations like this starts paying off with four to five binary flags, when readability of if-then-else chains approaches the border of what a typical human reader could handle.

Comment: Okay so that makes a bite more sense but how do I use it? I get this https://gyazo.com/a16c23fd265eb67b5ddbc13975c274e4 and this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
"

Comment: Where do I add if () **do stuff**

Comment: `where do I add if() do stuff` - put each different kind of `doStuff` into your 8192-long array of actions.

Comment: Would you mind updating you answer to give me an example? Sorry still learning this method is brand new to me,.

Comment: @JonnyKhanas I edited to fix the nullable "bool" problem.

Comment: Oh I think I got it!

Comment: That works just perfectly! I assume that this is how it works.. if 0(Mask) is = 1 then do this otherwise dont do anything? Sorry i'm really bad at explaining things.

Comment: @JonnyKhanas When mask is zero it means that nothing has been checked. When mask is 1, only checkbox 0 has been checked. 2 means checkbox 1, 3 means checkboxes 0 and 1 together, and so on, in a binary pattern.